# Using knockout in SharePoint for reading list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, visual-studio, knockoutjs

I have used the below code for reading list items. But when I try to debug this code, the functions are not getting called..

```
'use strict';
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
    }
}

hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(
  getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));

appweburl = decodeURIComponent(
getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

$(function() {
ko.applyBindings(new crudViewModel);
});

var crudViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var listName = "CategoryList";

    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.Title = ko.observable();
    self.CategoryName = ko.observable();

    self.Category = {
        Id: self.Id,
        Title: self.Title,
        CategoryName: self.CategoryName
    };



    self.Categories = ko.observableArray();
    self.error = ko.observable();


    **//Function to Read all Categories** 
    self.getCategories = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('CategoryList')/items/?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d.results);
                self.Categories(data.d.results);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                self.error("Error in processing request " + data.success);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

**For UI**

```
 <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
       <table id="tbl">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Id</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txtid" data-bind='value: id' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CategoryId</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txtcatid" data-bind='value: title' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CategoryName</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txtcatname" data-bind='value: categoryname' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <button data-bind='click: clear'>New</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button data-bind='click: createcategory'>Create</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button data-bind='click: updatecategory'>Update</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="Container">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Category Id</th>
                                <th>Category Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind='foreach: categories'>
                            <tr data-bind='click: getselectedcategory'>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind='text: Id'></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind='text: title'></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind='text: categoryname'></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button data-bind='click: deletecategory'>Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>




<div>
    <span data-bind="text: error"></span>
</div>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're never using `ko.applyBindings` which will get your markup and javascript talking.

You don't really need the reference to `context` or `user` since your view model seems to rely on REST.

I would just use a jQuery ready somewhere in your file and call `applyBindings` and instantiate a new view model:

```
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new crudViewModel());
});
```